# Android Google Cloud

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I saw this Tutorial about Google Cloud Messaging [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

So do all thing in above tutorial step by step >

I was upload file **gcm_server_php** to my host website .

but now I want to know how I can get APY Key and my Project number ?

this is someting from tutorial I do >

```
package com.androidhive.pushnotifications;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public final class CommonUtilities {

    // give your server registration url here
    static final String SERVER_URL = "Server_url"; 

    // Google project id
    static final String SENDER_ID = "Sender_ID"; 

    /**
     * Tag used on log messages.
     */
    static final String TAG = "AndroidHive GCM";

    static final String DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION =
            "com.androidhive.pushnotifications.DISPLAY_MESSAGE";

    static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";

    /**
     * Notifies UI to display a message.
     * <p>
     * This method is defined in the common helper because it's used both by
     * the UI and the background service.
     *
     * @param context application's context.
     * @param message message to be displayed.
     */
    static void displayMessage(Context context, String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

I don't understand what is mean server_url > I think it's mean my website where I upload file ?